# JQuery on template which is displayed by ListView, How to Trigger play on each object separately?

Tags: jquery, django, listview, templates, django-templates

My template

```js
{% for maingallery in gallery %}

    <div id="frame">
    <h1 id="mainimagetitle">{{ maingallery.title }}</h1>
       <a href="{% url 'gallery_detail' maingallery.id %}"><img id="mainimage" src="{{ maingallery.main_image1.url }}"/></a>
    <p id="mainimagetext">{{ maingallery.text }}</p>




<audio id="jazzy">
  <source src="{{ maingallery.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#mainimage").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('notactive');
            if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
              $("#jazzy").addClass('active').removeClass('notactive');
            }
            if ($("#jazzy").hasClass('active')) {
              $("#jazzy").trigger("play");
            }

            });
            $("#mainimage").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('notactive');
            if($(this).hasClass('notactive')) {
              $("#jazzy").addClass('notactive').removeClass('active');
            }
            if ($("#jazzy").hasClass('notactive')) {
              $("#jazzy").trigger("pause");
            }

            });
             });

        </script>
        </div>
{% endfor %}

   {% block content %}

   {% endblock %}
```

My problem:

I List few objects on template each of them has different sound file, and now i would like to achieve: When mouseon object 1 then sound for this object is triggered etc...

Till now i have achieved that when mouseon object 1 then sound is triggered but it isnt working on rest of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code will have several elements with the "mainimagetitle" id. You have to add a loop index or object id.

And you can use the class attribute in your JS code.

```html
{% for maingallery in gallery %}
    <div id="frame-{{ maingallery.id }}">
    <h1 id="mainimagetitle-{{ maingallery.id }}" class="mainimagetitleclass">...</h1>
    <div id="frame-{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <h1 id="mainimagetitle-{{ forloop.counter }}" class="mainimagetitleclass">...</h1>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".mainimagetitleclass").mouseover(function(){...});
        ...
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help Mikhail V. your answer was very helpful ;) although i am not sure if i did it exactly as you showed me

```js
{% for maingallery in gallery %}


    <div id="frame">
    <h1 id="mainimagetitle">{{ maingallery.title }}</h1>
       <a href="{% url 'gallery_detail' maingallery.id %}"><img class="mainimageclass" id="mainimage-{{ forloop.counter }}" src="{{ maingallery.main_image1.url }}"/></a>
    <p id="mainimagetext">{{ maingallery.text }}</p>




<audio class="mainimageaudio" id="jazzy-{{ forloop.counter }}">
  <source src="{{ maingallery.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>


        </div>
          <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#mainimage-{{ forloop.counter }}").mouseenter(function(){
       $("#jazzy-{{ forloop.counter }}").trigger('play');
       });
       $("#mainimage-{{ forloop.counter }}").mouseleave(function(){
       $("#jazzy-{{ forloop.counter }}").trigger('pause').prop("currentTime",0);
       });
       });


        </script>



{% endfor %}
```

I used forloop counter because string with id is not working in my case, actually i am amazed because i thought it is not possible to use django template in jquery string, everything works properly so i cannot be so wrong as i did it.

Still last question, i use audio files in ogg format, but when i trigger play by event it is not run so quickly, i have some short delay, about 0.5s -1s, but i think it can be fault of audio format, maybe some advices which format is best for audio files, i heard that it is good to add few formats for one file.